# Remove object from UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage, uicollectionview

I want to remove an object from a `UIImageView`. In the collection I've got 36 UIImageViews that I use to randomly rotate and change the images. But after this code;

```
self.ImageViews[5].image = UIImage(named: "squirrel")
```

I want to remove the object (`ImageViews[5]`) so that it no longer will be changed ---- thereby I think deleting it temporary from the `UICollectionView` is the best solution.

Something like this?

```
ImageViews = ImageViews.filter() { $0 != ImageViews[5] }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make also one array -

`filteredImageViews = ImageViews.filter() { $0 != ImageViews[5] }`

And fill collection view from filteredImageViews. So, when need remove image from collection view make this:

```
collectionView.performBatchUpdates(
{
    filteredImageViews = ImageViews.filter() { $0 != ImageViews[5] }
    collectionView.deleteItemsAtIndexPaths(NSIndexPath(forItem: 5, inSection: 0))
},
completion: nil)
```

Comment: `[UIImageView]` has no member 'performBatchUpdates'

Comment: @RappeStegarn, not imageView.collectionView.performBatchUpdates, but - collectionView.performBatchUpdates. Call method performBatchUpdates for  collectionView.

Comment: @RappeStegarn, but you have some collection view with some name. collectionView it name for example

Comment: No I don't think I have a collection view, should I?

Comment: @RappeStegarn, then i don't understand your question. Why u write about  UICollectionView?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114969/discussion-between-savchenko-dmitry-and-rappe-stegarn).